# Difference in hvac (split unit) pipe size between installed pipes and requirements of new equipment

Tags: hvac

1. Looked at  LG split unit AC and the specs give a required pipe size of 1/4" and 3/8". Assume this is O.D.
2. The problem is that I have pipes O.D. 1/4" and 1/2" installed. Can I run the new LG split which requires 1/4" and  3/8" on my existing pipes? My installed suction line is  1/8" bigger than the LG specs but the  existing liquid line matches the specs. Changing piping is not an option.
3. In case of possible performance issues, what would be the remedies? Adjusting the operating PSI slightly, adjusting the BTU of the units or any other?
   Many thanks
   Peer

Comment: The 3/8 vs 1/2 is the return line, so not so critical in the operation. The condenser coil will have 3/8 so from your heat exchanger to condenser coil using 1/2 should not be a problem.

Comment: Why would you think that pipes are given as OD - pipe sizes are virtually **always** nominal ID.  The OD is always larger than the "size" becasue the size is the size of the hole inside the pipe (and it's ofter actually slightly larger than the nominal size, for that matter.) So the 1/4" OD line is, in fact, too small, and the 1/2" OD line is probably the correct size.